# Normalize Array in Python

Tags: python

I have an array

```
ar= [2, 3, 45 , 5556, 6, 'empty', 4]
```

I'd like to normalize this array in order to plot it later.

```
0:2
1:3
2:45
3: 5556
4: 6
5: 0  # not "empty" anymore
6: 4

newAr = {if (ar[i] != 'empty') ar[i] : i for i in range(len(ar))
         else: ar[i] = 0 }
```

I tried this way, How can I normilize this array with condition of converting every 'empty' element with zero.

**UPDATE**
The main goal is to normalize this array.
Axe X: for index, Axe Y for the value.

what if we have duplicates, how can we make sure that we have the right references.

```
 ar= [2, 3, 45, 4 , 5556, 6, 'empty', 4]

  0:2
    1:3
    2:45
    3: 5556
    4: 6
    5: 0  # not "empty" anymore
    6: 4
```

Comment: Where do you get such an aweful array out of? serious question.

Comment: I am trying to clean dataSet, I give this example to get one of the conditions that I am working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
ar = [2, 3, 45, 5556, 6, 'empty', 4]
new_ar = [0 if x == 'empty' else x for x in ar]
```

yields:

```
[2, 3, 45, 5556, 6, 0, 4]
```

I used the Python [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python) at the *front* of the list comprehension, instead of after.

**Edit:** If you need a set, as per comment, then simply use `{}` instead of `[]` in your comprehension:

```
new_ar = {0 if x == 'empty' else x for x in ar}
```

This will automatically ensure unique values only.

Comment: Thanks!  
How can we hash them in case we have duplicates, for example (we have 4 two times, the main goal is to plot these data. Axe X: is for the array index and the Axe Y for ar[i]) I shouldn't have duplicates .

Comment: Just turn your list into a set: `set(new_ar)` will remove duplicates. I'll add that to my answer. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: In this case I need to get the new_ar as a list: Does this work  new_ar = {0 if x == 'empty' else x for x in list(set(ar))}

Comment: Turning a `list` into a `set` would kill the ordering. Since @user3047512 wants to plot this data, I'm leaning more towards `dict`s or such. Still, the question about handling conflicts remains

Comment: @user3047512: `list(set(ar))` is pointless in the expression that you've written. The more pressing concern is preserving the ordering of data, so that the plot stays true to the original indices

Comment: You could use `OrderedDict` and simply write out the long form of the comprehension, if you wanted to preserve order. There's no *need* for it to be a one-liner. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: I though about Dictionaries, hashing will make values unique and can get them easily. I am not familiar with using Dictionaries/hashing on python. Can you give a hint

Comment: The ordering is not important.

Comment: @user3047512: I can't imagine a plot with ordering being unimportant. In either case, check out the edit in my post. I've figured out what I needed to know from your edited post and updated my answer appropriately

Comment: @user3047512 if ordering is unimportant, the set comprehension will work fine, see last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [91]: ar = [2, 3, 45, 5556, 6, 'empty', 4]

In [92]: [i if not isinstance(i, str) else 0 for i in ar]
Out[92]: [2, 3, 45, 5556, 6, 0, 4]
```

OR

```
In [93]: [i if i!='empty' else 0 for i in ar]
Out[93]: [2, 3, 45, 5556, 6, 0, 4]
```

Based on your updated post, this should handle the appropriate removal of duplicates:

```
In [105]: d = {n if n!='empty' else 0:i for i,n in enumerate(ar)}

In [106]: newList = [None]*len(d)

In [107]: for n,i in d.iteritems(): newList[i] = n

In [108]: newList
Out[108]: [2, 3, 45, 5556, 6, 0, 4]
```

Comment: How can we hash them in case we have duplicates, for example (we have 4 two times)

Comment: @user3047512: where do we have 4 twice? Also, how do you want to handle conflicts ("if two indices contain `x`, which index should be ignored?")?