# Turning Json object to an array

Tags: python, json

I have a JSon object that is written this way.

```
Data= [{
  "code" : "001",
  "city" : "Boston",
  "zipcode":"067"
  },{
  "code" : "002",
  "city" : "NY",
  },{
  "city" : "NewJersey",
  }]
```

In order to get a specific value "Code" in an array, I make this way.

```
ar= Data["code"].Values
```

When I print results I got

```
ar = [001, 002 ,'nan']
```

'nan' seems like the empty value. 
How can I get only data that exist in the field without taking in consideration these fields where we don't find "code" attribute in ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7 ! I did import Json using pandas as pd Pd.read_json()

Comment: That is illegal code in python2.7. I just tried it. `Data` is a list and can only use `int` indices, not `str` indices

Comment: Also, that's not JSON what you show here. That's an array of dictionaries, which makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown us is not JSON. It's a `list` of `dict`s. If you want to get all the `'code'` values out of those `dict`s, then you could do this:

```
[d['code'] for d in Data if 'code' in d]
```

Comment: I still get 'nan' elements in the list when I print it . Let's tackle the problem frpm different corner. Can we delete empty values

Comment: @user3047512 That's a duplicate of [the question you asked just before posting this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20276598/198633), which has valid answers on it